# How to get my file from a form and insert it into a folder in my project?

Tags: php, html

i am creating a paltform, and there is a page "insertPage.php" containing a form, where the 'teacher' can upload his course and students can see it ..

my form worked perfectly when i used only $_POST to get my data but when i used $_FILES it didnt work ..

here is my html code :

```
<form method="post" action="insertion.php">

   <input name="file" type="file"><br>

</form>
```

And here is my insertion.php Page :

```
$file = "photo-".$_FILES["file"]["name"];

if(isset($_POST["titre"]) && isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]) && isset($_POST["niveau"]) && isset($_POST["filliere"]) && isset($_POST["format"]) && isset($_POST["matiere"]) && isset($_POST["type"])){

copy($_FILES["tmp_name"]["file"],"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Platforme/Files/".$file);

$req = "insert into courses(nomCourse,type,format,file,matiere,module) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$data = array($titre,$type_text,$format_text,$file,$matiere,$module);

$gdb->insertIntoBD($req,$data);

}
```

i get nothing in my database, That's why i need some help, Thank you guys ..

Comment: It's `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`

Comment: You should have gotten a warning about undefined index because you had that backwards. Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled when you're debugging.

Comment: missing an valid enctype

Comment: Fred .. Thank you for that :) ..

Comment: Barmar .. No i dont think so, i didnt have enctype attributes in my html code .. but thank you for your time and help